# Why was this question cloesed?

Tags: discussion

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/80020/gift-for-contractor-who-did-amazing-work

One upvote, no down-votes, one up-voted answer, and an appropriate work-place topic for this time of year.

No community close votes, just the action of one moderator.

Comment: Minor comment here: Oded is technically a Stack Exchange employee and thus has moderator privileges on all sites, but isn't explicitly a moderator here.

Comment: @enderland It struck me as strange because the moderation here is usually content for the community to police itself.

Comment: @RichardU - I suspect Oded was just on the site and saw the question which is the type explicitly forbidden (asking for a list of possible answers) by the SE rules, and closed it.  It was probably not that it required immediate action so much as a chance occurance.

Answer (score 5):

It really isn't in scope here. It asks for thoughts or opinions on buying a gift!

That's nothing to do with Workplace.SE or even work.

Not sure why you think it would be in scope, to be honest.

Comment: Right, and the community would have voted it down.  I was wondering what was so offensive/wrong about it that it required immediate moderator action.

Answer (score 4):

Well, reason given is "Primarily opinion based" which I normally am pretty dubious of because by definition, almost everything on Workplace is opinion based.

This question is the rare exception where I think it fits because I find it to be not primarily opinion based but totally opinion based.

This is a Q&A site. There can really be no answer that is better than others and certainly not one that is best. What is the goal that's being addressed? What problem is really being solved?  Instead of a question that we can answer, we have an opinion poll or survey.

Comment: I guess : "ask his friends or coworkers" is the only answer which is.. quite obvious.

Answer (score 4):

The basic question was:

> Is there any type of gift I can get for him on a personal level?

How could anyone here reasonably expect to offer anything other than an opinion, when "personal level" is requested for someone we cannot know?

Answer (score 0):

One way this question can be saved may be to turn it into a question about appropriateness of giving any gift.

Possible avenues that answers may take:

- The question says "He and his staff were always there when we needed assistance". What happens when they don't get a gift?
- If the contractor works for a company they may require the receiver of the gift to reject it, or turn it over to the company, or share it with the entire team.

Of course what you think is a good gift may not be: [How to return a fake watch "gifted" by a client](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/74169/how-to-return-a-fake-watch-gifted-by-a-client)